# GSON - Ignore null fields when deserializing

Tags: java, gson

I have a simple POJO class with a few fields:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ObjectB {

  String field_B1;
  String field_B2;
  String field_B3;
  String field_B4;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

field 1 and 2 can be set, and 3 and 4 can be set, but no other configuration.  When I POST to my DB, the serialization works and I only see two values in my JSON object to represent ObjectB.  However, when I make a GET call to my webapp, I see `{field_B1:"ghi",field_B2:"jkl",field_B3:null,field_B4:null}`.  I want to ignore the null values when deserializing the data.  Since I am returning the POJO class, is this impossible?  Do I always have to return null values?

Comment: By default Gson ignores null field for serialization, we can set to include them by using `GsonBuilder` and calling `serializeNulls()`. But not sure about deserialization.

Comment: @Mayur yeah, it serializes fine, and I can see the DB values look correct.  However, when reading the data back, it shows the null fields, when I want to exclude them, even though they are a part of the POJO